# ZF2 DB based session management vs Redis

Tags: redis, zend-framework2

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this.

I am writing a PHP and ZF2 based website that needs to be scalable. So, I am looking into Database based sessions. I understand ZF2 supports DB Session management, so I can create a MySQL DB, and use it. But DB session management could be slow. So, I have looked into redis as a cache management solution.

My question is will using redis as a standalone server work for both server side session management and a cache solution (as it seems to have it's own in memory DB) or do I need to combine it with ZF2 DB Session management?

Comment: I dont see why not. I use redis for ZF2 to store a users token and with that i manage users. Dont see why you couldnt store stuff that you would store in the session in redis cache and manage as you like

Comment: Given loading the session data from the DB is only a single row on a (hopefully) uniquely index table, MySQL can execute this query way faster than you probably think (i.e. thounds of such queries /sec). As suggested, you sure can store the session data in Redis as well, the required Storage interfaces are all available and I'm pretty sure someone has done this already. For me this sounds like too early optimization though. Other areas of your code probably would be a bottle neck earlier than this single query :)

Comment: @Daedalus So, you think if I use Redis, I don't need to use ZF2 DB Session Management and if I use ZF2 DB session Management, I don't need to use Redis. Is that right?

Comment: @Fge I am still considering what to do architecture wise, as this needs to be scalable to tens of 1000s of users and I didn't want the reads to be slow.

Comment: I use both. At first all session. When a user logs in, I store his user_id, then for every ajax call to apigility APIs I checked the $_SESSION for the user's id, to make sure I do specific queries for that user. But if you have many ajax calls going out to many APIs and each API is checking the $_SESSION file for user ID than they would just stack up in Q, till the API let go of the $_SESSION, which would allow the next one to check in the file. This slowed down a lot of processes, so I began to introduce redis and caching. Sped everything up! long story short: you can use both.